# copy paste from Putty on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: putty

I have a hard time copy and paste from Putty.
I believe I've tried every option I read in this forum.
Please assist me

Comment: As we can not (yet) read you mind, you have to give more explanation.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is out of support, upgrade.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: FYI:   This is a Q&A site, https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: Neverthelss I need that specific version for petalinux distribution. So for now I cannot install other. I have Ubuntu 18.04.06 , and Putty software I need to see the log from Xilinx board. All i want to do is copy the log from putty. i understand that if it is working in windows, is not gaurunteed to work on linux too. Is there other more reliable client console for Ubuntu?